# How to optimize generic SQL to retrieve DDL information

Tags: firebird

I have a generic code that is used to retrieve DDL information from a Firebird database (FB2.1). It generates SQL code like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where 'c' <> 'c'
```

I cannot change this code. Actually, if that matters, it is inside Report Builder 10.

The fact is that some tables from my database are becoming a litle too populated (>1M records) and that query is starting to take too long to execute.

If I try to execute

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where SomeIndexedField = SomeImpossibleValue
```

it will obviously use that index and run very quickly.

Well, it wouldn´t be that hard to the database find out that that is an impossible matcher and make some sort of optimization and avoid testing it against each row.

Is there any way to make my firebird database to optimize that search?

Comment: You need to remove condition with <>. I don't know for what reason report builder inserts this condition. May be there is some check mark "avoid indexes" or "use natural scan". This is a question for report builder not Firebird.

Comment: It includes that condition in order to get only DDL, no data at all. It could be 1<>1, 1=0, anything that always results false. The fact is that other databases optimize it and FB do not.

Comment: I see. I was misguided by usage of DDL word in this context. Actually, Firebird has PREPARE stage which allows receive all information about fields and parameters without a query being executed. Seems that Report Builder doesn't know anything about it. And the answer still NO, Firebird will not optimise this useless query.

Comment: I guess that RB is trying to be compatible with other databases by preparing a standard SQL statement. There are many ways to optimize it to FB, but I guess they want to be standard.

Answer (score 1):

As the filter condition is a negative proposition (and also doesn't refer a column to search, but only a value to compare to another value), Firebird need to do a full table scan (without use any index) to confirm that aren't any record that meet your criteria.

If you can't change you need to wait for the upcoming 3.0 version, that will implement the [Boolean data type](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-726), and therefore should start to evaluate "constant" fake comparisons in advance (maybe the client library will do this evaluation before send the statement to the server?).